# How do I go back when I view a certain git hash

Tags: plugin-fugitive

I'm using the [vim-fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) plugin for git blame annotations.

When I'm on a certain line, I type `:Gblame` and it shows me the git commits:

[image]

When I click on a git commit hash, I go to it, how can go back to the original view?

Bonus: how can I make the git hash appear on a split view instead of jumping to it?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the jump list to go back to your file: pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> will bring you back to the top of the commit file and pressing it a second time will bring you back to the file you were editing. (see [`:h CTRL-O`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#CTRL-O) and [`:h jumplist`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#jumplist))

To open the commit in a split window [`:h fugitive-:Gblame`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/blob/master/doc/fugitive.txt#L210-L228) tells you that you can use <kbd>o</kbd> when you are on the commit line. You can also use <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> to open it in a new tab.

*Note*: Instead of clicking on the commit hash you can also use <kbd>Enter</kbd> to go to the commit message.

Answer (score 1):

***Update***: I read "original view" in the question as referring to the git blame view. If instead it is meant to refer to the source code file, then [@statox's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/14158/343) is the correct one.

I don't think fugitive provides a mechanism for going back to the previous blame view.

If you make a note of the buffer number *before* you jump to the commit (with commands such as `:ls!` or `:echo bufnr("")`), then you can jump back to it by passing a `count` to the `:b` command, but fugitive's mappings no longer appear to be set up.

You can make the hash appear in a split view instead of jumping to it by pressing <kbd>o</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>. (See `:help :Gblame`.)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use `o` or `O` to open commit in a split or net tab. That way the blame is still there and you can use it as a reference.

You can use `g?` to see `:Gblame`'s help or go to `:h fugitive-:Gblame`